# Largest product in a grid

Tags: java, algorithm, math, logic

I'm stuck with this problem. I do think I've got the right solution but when submitting it to the website, it does not accept it.

I tried debugging it by printing all the possible combinations and they're all done (horizontally, vertically and diagonally). The array is filled correctly also. I checked it by printing it after.

Do you know where the problem may be?

### Question

> What is the greatest product of four adjacent numbers in the same
>   direction (up, down, left, right, or diagonally) in the 20×20 grid?

[Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/problem=11)

### Code

```
String product = 
          "08 02 22 97 38 15 00 40 00 75 04 05 07 78 52 12 50 77 91 08 "
        + "49 49 99 40 17 81 18 57 60 87 17 40 98 43 69 48 04 56 62 00 "
        + "81 49 31 73 55 79 14 29 93 71 40 67 53 88 30 03 49 13 36 65 "
        + "52 70 95 23 04 60 11 42 69 24 68 56 01 32 56 71 37 02 36 91 "
        + "22 31 16 71 51 67 63 89 41 92 36 54 22 40 40 28 66 33 13 80 "
        + "24 47 32 60 99 03 45 02 44 75 33 53 78 36 84 20 35 17 12 50 "
        + "32 98 81 28 64 23 67 10 26 38 40 67 59 54 70 66 18 38 64 70 "
        + "67 26 20 68 02 62 12 20 95 63 94 39 63 08 40 91 66 49 94 21 "
        + "24 55 58 05 66 73 99 26 97 17 78 78 96 83 14 88 34 89 63 72 "
        + "21 36 23 09 75 00 76 44 20 45 35 14 00 61 33 97 34 31 33 95 "
        + "78 17 53 28 22 75 31 67 15 94 03 80 04 62 16 14 09 53 56 92 "
        + "16 39 05 42 96 35 31 47 55 58 88 24 00 17 54 24 36 29 85 57 "
        + "86 56 00 48 35 71 89 07 05 44 44 37 44 60 21 58 51 54 17 58 "
        + "19 80 81 68 05 94 47 69 28 73 92 13 86 52 17 77 04 89 55 40 "
        + "04 52 08 83 97 35 99 16 07 97 57 32 16 26 26 79 33 27 98 66 "
        + "88 36 68 87 57 62 20 72 03 46 33 67 46 55 12 32 63 93 53 69 "
        + "04 42 16 73 38 25 39 11 24 94 72 18 08 46 29 32 40 62 76 36 "
        + "20 69 36 41 72 30 23 88 34 62 99 69 82 67 59 85 74 04 36 16 "
        + "20 73 35 29 78 31 90 01 74 31 49 71 48 86 81 16 23 57 05 54 "
        + "01 70 54 71 83 51 54 69 16 92 33 48 61 43 52 01 89 19 67 48 ";

Scanner sc = new Scanner(product);
int[][] in = new int[20][20];
for (int i = 0 ; i < 20 ; i++){
    for (int j = 0 ; j < 20 ; j++){
        in[i][j] = sc.nextInt();
    }
}

int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
int tmp = 0;

for (int i = 0 ; i < 20 ; i++){
    for (int j = 0 ; j < 20 ; j++){
        if (i < 17){
            tmp = in[i][j] * in[i+1][j] * in[i+2][j] * in[i+3][j];
            if (tmp > max) max = tmp;
        }
        if (j < 17){
            tmp = in[i][j] * in[i][j+1] * in[i][j+2] * in[i][j+3];
            if (tmp > max) max = tmp;
        }
        if (j < 17 && i < 17){
            tmp = in[i][j] * in[i+1][j+1] * in[i+2][j+2] * in[i+3][j+3];
            if (tmp > max) max = tmp;
        }
    }
}

System.out.println(max);
```

### Output

```
51267216
```

Comment: Sounds like project euler, problem 11.

Comment: @Tunaki that's it exactly. I do not understand why I'm stuck with this. EDIT : I added the source link.

Comment: how do you know? what is the correct answer?

Comment: @sharonbn I do not know the correct answer. I have to submit it and they accept it or refuse it.

Comment: I think it's because you only check for diagonals in one direction, namely down-right. You don't check for diagonals that go upwards.

Comment: @Arc676 You may be right, I'll add a test.

Comment: Technically someone else already posted an answer, but I posted anyway. If anyone thinks I shouldn't have, please comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only check one diagonal, namely the one that goes in the down-right direction.

Going up-right:

```
if (i < 17 && j > 2){
    tmp = in[i][j] * in[i+1][j-1] * in[i+2][j-2] * in[i+3][j-3];
    if (tmp > max) max = tmp;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Do not worry, you were the first to answer actually so it is ok.

Answer (score 3):

You are only checking one diagonal, you need to check the other one as well:

```
if(j > 2 && i < 17) {
    tmp = in[i][j] * in[i+1][j-1] * in[i+2][j-2] * in[i+3][j-3];
    if (tmp > max) max = tmp;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Correct answer :).

Answer (score -1):

Largest product in a grid

Input

```
89 90 95 97 38 15 00 40 00 75 04 05 07 78 52 12 50 77 91 08  
49 49 99 40 17 81 18 57 60 87 17 40 98 43 69 48 04 56 62 00  
81 49 31 73 55 79 14 29 93 71 40 67 53 88 30 03 49 13 36 65  
52 70 95 23 04 60 11 42 69 24 68 56 01 32 56 71 37 02 36 91  
22 31 16 71 51 67 63 89 41 92 36 54 22 40 40 28 66 33 13 80  
24 47 32 60 99 03 45 02 44 75 33 53 78 36 84 20 35 17 12 50  
32 98 81 28 64 23 67 10 26 38 40 67 59 54 70 66 18 38 64 70  
67 26 20 68 02 62 12 20 95 63 94 39 63 08 40 91 66 49 94 21  
24 55 58 05 66 73 99 26 97 17 78 78 96 83 14 88 34 89 63 72  
21 36 23 09 75 00 76 44 20 45 35 14 00 61 33 97 34 31 33 95  
78 17 53 28 22 75 31 67 15 94 03 80 04 62 16 14 09 53 56 92  
16 39 05 42 96 35 31 47 55 58 88 24 00 17 54 24 36 29 85 57  
86 56 00 48 35 71 89 07 05 44 44 37 44 60 21 58 51 54 17 58  
19 80 81 68 05 94 47 69 28 73 92 13 86 52 17 77 04 89 55 40  
04 52 08 83 97 35 99 16 07 97 57 32 16 26 26 79 33 27 98 66  
88 36 68 87 57 62 20 72 03 46 33 67 46 55 12 32 63 93 53 69  
04 42 16 73 38 25 39 11 24 94 72 18 08 46 29 32 40 62 76 36  
20 69 36 41 72 30 23 88 34 62 99 69 82 67 59 85 74 04 36 16  
20 73 35 29 78 31 90 01 74 31 49 71 48 86 81 16 23 57 05 54  
01 70 54 71 83 51 54 69 16 92 33 48 61 43 52 01 89 19 67 48
```

Output

73812150

```
import java.util.Scanner;                                            
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[][] in = new int[20][20];

    // Taking user input for the grid
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
            in[i][j] = sc.nextInt();
        }
    }

    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int tmp = 0;

    // Calculate maximum product
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
            if (i < 17) {
                tmp = in[i][j] * in[i + 1][j] * in[i + 2][j] * in[i + 3][j];
                if (tmp > max) max = tmp;
            }
            if (j < 17) {
                tmp = in[i][j] * in[i][j + 1] * in[i][j + 2] * in[i][j + 3];
                if (tmp > max) max = tmp;
            }
            if (j < 17 && i < 17) {
                tmp = in[i][j] * in[i + 1][j + 1] * in[i + 2][j + 2] * in[i + 3][j + 3];
                if (tmp > max) max = tmp;
            }
            if (i < 17 && j > 2) { 
                tmp = in[i][j] * in[i + 1][j - 1] * in[i + 2][j - 2] * in[i + 3][j - 3];
                if (tmp > max) max = tmp;
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println(max);
}}
```

Comment: I repeat my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71300468/highly-divisible-triangular-number/78218867#comment137908355_78218867) from your other answer, namely: Answers that contain only code are generally considered poor quality.