# Highly divisible triangular number

Tags: java

### Highly divisible triangular number, my solution

My solution of challenge from Project Euler takes too much time to execute. Although on lower numbers it works fine. Anyone could look up to my code and give me any advice to improve it?
The content of the task is:

> The sequence of triangle numbers is generated by adding the natural numbers. So the 7th triangle number would be 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 = 28. The first ten terms would be:
> 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45, 55, ...
> Let us list the factors of the first seven triangle numbers:
> (1: 1),
> (3: 1,3),
> (6: 1,2,3,6),
> (10: 1,2,5,10),
> (15: 1,3,5,15),
> (21: 1,3,7,21),
> (28: 1,2,4,7,14,28).
> We can see that 28 is the first triangle number to have over five divisors.
> What is the value of the first triangle number to have over five hundred divisors?

```
 `public static void main(String[] args) {
        int sum = 0;
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++) {
            sum += i;
            for (int j = 1; j <= sum; j++) {
                if (sum % j == 0) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            if (count > 500) {
                System.out.println(sum);
                break;
            } else {
                count = 0;
            }
        }

    }`
```

Comment: This question might be more appropriate on codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: I disagree with Green Cloak Guy.  The code review site is for improving code that works.  I don't think this code works, as I would expect the answer to be greater than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

Comment: I can't remember how I have done it, but an idea might be: find the prime factorization of the triangular number (maybe using also that you already know it is n*(n+1)/2) and search for a fast formula of the number of divisors knowing the factorization. Have fun!

Comment: Don't perform trial division up to `sum`; factors come in pairs, one of which is always less than or equal to the square root of the number.

Comment: If `i` gets anywhere near `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, `sum` is going to overflow. `Math.addExact` can help avoid that.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem The answer fits comfortably in a 32-bit int, and I just found it (again) with a variation on OP's program. It takes about 130 milliseconds on my laptop.

Comment: @DavidConrad Wow, that's interesting and surprising.  I was imagining that OP would have to do all kinds of clever tricks with storing primes in one array, and factor counts in another.  I'm sure one could write a program that works super fast; but 130ms is fast enough in anyone's books.

Comment: If n is even, then n+1 and n/2 are coprime, so the number of factors of n(n+1)/2 is the number of factors of n+1 times the number of factors of n/2.  If n is odd, then (n+1)/2 and n are coprime, so the number of factors of n(n+1)/2 is the number of factors of (n+1)/2 times the number of factors of n.  So you could start building an array that stores the number of factors of n if n is odd, or of n/2 if n is even.  Stop when you get two consecutive values whose product exceeds 500.  This will be lightning fast.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Thank you for the tip, im beginner in coding, would u mind typing these words to the code? Your explanation is clear but i don't know how to introduce it in code.

Answer (score 0):

Consider any set of primes **(p<sub>1</sub>, p<sub>2</sub>, p<sub>3</sub>. . . p<sub>n</sub>)** that factor a given number. Then the total number of divisors of that number are the products of **(e<sub>1</sub> + 1, e<sub>2</sub> + 1, e<sub>3</sub> + 1 ... e<sub>n</sub>+1)** where **e** is the exponent of the corresponding prime factor (i.e. the number of times that prime divides some number **N**).

There are three pieces to this answer.

- The main driver code
- the method to find the prime divisors.
- and a `Primes` class that generates successive primes using an iterator.

**The Driver**

- first instantiate the `Primes` class and initialize the `triangleNo`
- Then continually generate the next triangular number until the returned divisor count meets the requirements.

```
Primes primes = new Primes();
long triangleNo = 0;
for (long i = 1;; i++) {
    triangleNo += i;
    
    int divisors = getDivisorCount(triangleNo, primes);
    if (divisors > 500) {
        System.out.println("No = " + triangleNo);
        System.out.println("Divisors = " + divisors);
        System.out.println("Nth Triangle = " + i);
        break;
    }
}
```

prints

```
No = 76576500
Divisors = 576
Nth Triangle = 12375       NOTE: this is the value n in n(n+1)/2.
```

**Finding the prime factors**

- takes a value to factor and an instance of the Primes class
- continues to test each prime for division, counting the number of times the remainder is 0.
- a running product `totalDivisors` is computed.
- the loop continues until `t` is reduced to `1` or the current prime exceeds the square root of the original value.

```
public static int getDivisorCount(long t, Primes primes) {
    primes.reset();
    Iterator<Integer> iter = primes;
    int totalDivisors = 1;
    long sqrtT = (long)Math.sqrt(t);
    while (t > 1 && iter.hasNext()) {
        int count = 0;
        int prime = iter.next();
        while (t % prime == 0) {
            count++;
            t /= prime;
        }
        
        totalDivisors *= (count + 1);
        if (prime > sqrtT) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return totalDivisors;
}
```

**The Primes class**

- A class to generate primes with a resettable iterator (to preserve computed primes from previous runs the index of an internal list is set to 0.)
- an iterator was chosen to avoid generating primes which may not be required to obtain the desired result.
- A value to limit the largest prime may be specified or it may run to the default.
- Each value is tested by dividing by the previously computed primes.
- And either added to the current list or ignored as appropriate.
- if more primes are needed, `hashNext` invoked a generating to increase the number and returns true or false based on the limit.

```
class Primes implements Iterator<Integer> {
    private int lastPrime = 5;
    private List<Integer> primes =
            new ArrayList<>(List.of(2, 3, 5));
    private int index = 0;
    private int max = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    
    public Primes() {
    }
    
    public Primes(int max) {
        this.max = max;
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        if (index >= primes.size()) {
            generate(15); // add some more
        }
        return primes.get(index) < max;
    }
    
    @Override
    public Integer next() {
        return primes.get(index++);
    }
    
    private void generate(int n) {
        outer: for (int candidate = lastPrime + 2;;
                candidate += 2) {
            for (int p : primes) {
                if (p < Math.sqrt(candidate)) {
                    if (candidate % p == 0) {
                        continue outer;
                    }
                }
            }
            
            primes.add(candidate);
            lastPrime = candidate;
            if (n-- == 0) {
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    
    public void reset() {
        index = 0;
    }
}
```

Note:  It is very likely that this answer can be improved, by employing numerical shortcuts using concepts in the area of number theory or perhaps even basic algebra.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {

public static void main(String[] args) {

int [] primes = new int[1000];

primes[0] = 2;
primes[1] = 3;
primes[2] = 5;
primes[3] = 7;
int count1 = 4;
int num = 9;

int i = 0;

mainl:
while(num <= 1000000) {

    for(i=0;i<count1;i++) {
        if(num % primes[i] == 0) {
            break;
        }
        else if(primes[i] > (num/2)) {
            primes[count1] = num;
            count1++;

            if(count1 == 1000) {
                break mainl;
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    if(i == count1) {
        primes[count1] = num;
        count1++;

        if(count1 == 1000) {
            break mainl;
        }
    }

    num += 2;
}




Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int t = in.nextInt();
for(int a0 = 0; a0 < t; a0++){
    long n = in.nextLong();


    int j = 2;
long result = 1;
long sum = 1;
int count2 = 1;


while(true) {

    sum += j;
    long temp = sum;

    loop1:
    for(int k=0;k<1000;k++) {
        count2 = 1;
        while(true) {

            if(temp % primes[k] == 0) {
                temp /= primes[k];
                count2++;
            }
            else {
                break;
            }
        }
        result *= count2;
        if(temp == 1) {
            break loop1;
        }
    }
    if(result > n) {
        break;
    }
    else {
        result = 1;
    }

    j++;

}

System.out.println(sum);
}}}
```

Comment: Answers that contain only code are generally considered poor quality. Can you explain how your code works?